# x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, c, linux

I am trying to install a python library but I am getting an error

```
building '_pyFlask' extension
/home/lisa/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/lisagoh/anaconda3/include -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /home/lisa/anaconda3/include -fPIC -DFLASKCOMMIT="33a2752" -DHEALPIX_DATA="/mnt/c/Users/lisa_/OneDrive/Documents/Healpix_3.70/data" -DUSEXCOMPLEX=0 -DUSEMAP2TGA=0 -I/home/lisa/anaconda3/include/python3.8 -I/mnt/c/Users/lisa_/OneDrive/Documents/Healpix_3.70/include/healpix_cxx -c src/pyFlask_wrap.cxx -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/src/pyFlask_wrap.o -fopenmp
x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory
error: command '/home/lisa/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc' failed with exit status 1
```

I've tried `sudo apt-get g++`, `sudo apt-get upgrade`,`sudo apt-get update` and they tell me I have the latest versions but it still doesn't work.
When I try `g++ --print-prog-name=cc1plus` I get `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/cc1plus` but when I try to find the `cc1plus` file it does not exist. I'm using the Ubunto 20.04 on a Windows OS.

I'm new to Linux and any help will be greatly appreciated thank you!

Comment: The command `x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc` looks like a cross-compilation command. Have you installed the compiler for the `x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu` target (not for your native host)?

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure if I have...I only know that I installed anaconda...